# Consuming SOAP services in Angular 2

Tags: angular, soap

I wondering if someone could advise or point me to any resources on the web on how my Angular 2 app can consume a SOAP service? Unfortunately this is a legacy app so there is no REST alternative at this point. TIA!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could checkout this SOAP client service:
https://github.com/autopulous/angular2-soap/blob/master/src/soap.service.ts

It looks like it hasn't been updated in a while, but I'm assuming the SOAP service still works, maybe with some tweaking.