# Ionic 2 SOAP protocol

Tags: angularjs, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I need a SOAP protocol for ionic 2 and Angular 2, I did not find anything current on the internet for ionic 2, my request is as follows something like this:

```
POST / api HTTP / 1.1
Authorization: Basic dXN1YXJpbzpzZW5oYQ ==
Host: linker.zatix.com.br
Accept: * / *
Content-Type: text / xml; Charset = utf-8
Content-Length: 281
```

Answer (score 0):

You're probably not going to want to consume a soap service from angular2.  I'm sure you can force it to work, but it seems very unnatural.  You wouldn't want to consume soap in an ajax request would you?

[Consuming SOAP services in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40465131/consuming-soap-services-in-angular-2)

I would recommend you create a thin restful api that your Ionic/Angular2 app talks to that in turn talks to the soap service stack.

Comment: Would you have any good tutorials on how to make a restful api?